# retrofit 404 error

Tags: android, retrofit

Getting error on retrofit 404 for belowed code

```
 final RestAdapter restadapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint("http://trailermovie.in/android-webservice").build();

        api1 flowerapi = restadapter.create(api1.class);

        flowerapi.getData(new Callback<List<Example>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(List<Example> flowers, Response response) {
                flowerList = flowers;
                adapter1 adapt = new adapter1(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.item_file,flowerList);
                //ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                setListAdapter(adapt);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error+"Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("fdsf",error+"");
            }
        });
```

this is api call

```
@GET("/feeds/Example.json")
public void getData(Callback<List<Example>> response);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that this Endpoint exists ?
I think everything is correct here and this endpoint is just not existing.
A GET call with Postman on `http://trailermovie.in/android-webservice/feeds/Example.json` also returns 404 Not Found, so it should be correct.